# Mid 2011 iMac 27 inch 1 TB hard drive partitioned 50% Mac and 50% Win 7 bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, memory, boot-camp

Bought iMac from new. Works perfectly and installed bootcamp by dividing the 1TB drive 50/50. iMac came with 4GB RAM. Made enquiries and have found that there are 4 memory slots. Kept the 4GB and added 2 4GIG Ram modules to make full memory 12GIG. Installed Windows 32 bit and Office etc
In MAC states I have 12GIG Ram: In Windows native (I.e. booting to Win 7 without bootcamp) I see it states I have 12 GIG RAM but only 2.32 USABLE RAM. 
The whole point of upgrading the RAM was to get more available in the machine when bootcamp running. When running Win7 in bootcamp it simply says there is 2.32 usable RAM. BUT ... presumably Win 7 should run the full 4GIG when in native mode. 
I note somewhere here that if certain hardware is installed the RAM may be limited to 2.32 in Win 32 bit and someone upgraded to Win 64 bit to see then a magical change. Is that what I will have to do
Seems not right that Win 7 limits itself to 2.32 RAM particularly when it knows that 12 GIG RAM is installed.
Any ideas how to make it recoginise the full 4GIG that Win 7 32 bit is supposed to work with?
csr

Comment: 32-bit OSes just can't address more than 4 GB of RAM (unless PAE is enabled, but that's a different story). Your best option is to install 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

That's why there is 64 bit Windows...

Best I recall, the 2.32 is what's left of the 4 after Windows itself has sucked up 1.68GB of the 4GB. May have to to with [Graphics use of RAM](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/maximum-ram-for-windows-7-32-bit/4286bbfa-6851-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).